# How can you eliminate glass material seams when they are right next to each other?

Tags: transparency, glass

I am using a wave modifier to animate iphone glass.
I've broken up the glass into honeycomb units,
However, the 'seams' between the units can still be seen after it is joined back togther.
Is there any way I could make it so that when the side faces between units are touching each other, the seams would disappear; or somehow merge into a bigger piece?

Thanks a lot!

[image: here you can see the shape of the honey comb clearly]